# Google Sheets - Malware issue

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a current issue with Google sheets. I lost BTC, which I was trying to send to my Binance BTC deposit wallet. The displayed wallet address on the Binance page is currently manipulated by the Google Sheets extension in my chrome browser. I can prove that.Somebody must have infiltrated code into Google Sheets. The version is 2.1.

What is the recomendation to do now?Any help appreciated!

This is the ID on the disk... -> Extension\cndlnjmkininbfedkccimciopjkdcooq\5.1.9._0

best regards

Mark

Comment: Remove the extension. [Remove authorizations](//myaccount.google.com/permissions)??

Comment: This is a issue which apperas only in chrome based browsers with the Google Sheets extension.
The proposed answer is not apropriate!